# Plotting an average

Tags: python, arrays, plot

I want to plot an average of 24 arrays, but had an error message ''list' object has no attribute 'shape''. Where's the mistake?

```
empty_array=numpy.zeros[2,30,100]
for x in range (1,25):
    array = array[x,:,:,:]
    empty_array += array
average = map(lambda x:x/24,empty_array)

plt.figure(1)
plt.pcolor(average)
plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
```

Comment: `shape` is a attribute of `numpy.array` not `list` . In which line you got error.

Comment: @RahulKP in line 'plt.color(average)'

Answer (score 1):

`empty_array=[2,30,100]` does not create an empty array. It is a list containing three numbers. You are looking for [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

Comment: Of course. My mistake, I'm sorry. I mean, even after replacing it with zeros, the result was like that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to compute the average in one of the axis. You can simply use [`np.mean()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) for this. Example from docs:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> np.mean(a)
2.5
>>> np.mean(a, axis=0)
array([ 2.,  3.])
>>> np.mean(a, axis=1)
array([ 1.5,  3.5])
```

The key here is to correctly define the axis you want to average over.

Other mistakes:

- [`np.zeros()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) take a tuple describing the shape as an input, i.e. `np.zeros((2,30,100))`.
- The reason you get "'list' object has no attribute 'shape'" is that `average` is a python `list`. Lists in python has no attribute named `shape`. [`plt.pcolor()` expect a 2-D (numpy) array](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor).